# centering div with margin:auto is not working

Tags: html, css

Hi I haven't got the right concept about center div in nested divs.Here is my html .I want to center white background div.

```
 <div class="div1">
    <div class="img"></div>
</div>
<div class="div2">

</div>
```

and CSS

```
.div1{
    width :100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
}
.img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color : white;
    display: block;
    margin:  auto;
    bottom: 0%;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
    text-align: center;

}
.div2{
    width :100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #e65100;
}
```

I tried to center div using text-align:center but it was not working.
and the output is here [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.img {
   ...
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ep9co5g5/

Comment: amazing! it works! thank buddy I will make the right answer mark.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `left` and `translateX` to center it since you are using position absolute,

you need to add this css to **.img**

```
left:50%;
transform:translateX(-50%);
```

**see code snippet:**

```css
.div1{
    width :100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
}
.img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color : white;
    bottom: 0%;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
    left:50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);

}
.div2{
    width :100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #e65100;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
    <div class="img"></div>
</div>
<div class="div2">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.div1{
    width :100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
}
.img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color : white;
    display: block;
    margin:  auto;
    bottom: 0%;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
    text-align: center;
    left:0;
    right:0;

}
.div2{
    width :100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #e65100;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
    <div class="img"></div>
</div>
<div class="div2">

</div>
```